# What is a word for an inconsequential place or small errand?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose there are several small souvenirs I would like to buy while travelling.  I might call them *trinkets* or *knick-knacks*; generally, they are things that I want but are of little overall importance.

If instead I want to describe unimportant places I would like to stop while travelling, what would I call them?  As examples, perhaps I want to stop at a local bookstore, a grocery store, and a certain pier.  Like my souvenirs, these places aren't important (they certainly aren't *landmarks*), but I still would like to see them.

As an example sentence:

> I have several _____ to visit before I finish my vacation here.

Comment: Colloquially you could get away with calling them **pit stops** (brief rests, especially on a journey. If you used this I'd say "make" instead of "visit") though there's likely a more fitting term.

Comment: A wordier term would be **points/places of interest** but that doesn't denote that they're inconsequential.

Comment: @JohnClifford True, although *pit stops* suggests that they're necessary (I need food and a bathroom, for example) instead of places of (my) interest.  *Places of interest* is good but sounds like they're interesting to the general public, which isn't necessarily true.

Comment: Here in Scotland if we were running small errands we'd say we're away (to get) some messages. :)

Comment: If they are unimportant, how about just nondescript **places**?

Comment: You could use the noun _stops_, but that would work better with _make_ than _visit_: _I have several stops to make before I finish my vacation here_.

Comment: How about "I have several **unscheduled visits** to make before I finish..."?

Comment: *I have several corners to visit*... maybe? Or is it too ambiguous?

Comment: colloquially, "odds and sods"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To describe the diverse and not so important visits you make in the example I'd use:

> I have several [stops](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stop) to make before I finish my vacation here.

**Stop**
1.1 A break or halt during a journey:
*'allow an hour or so for driving and as long as you like for stops'*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stop

Answer (score 3):

How about:

> I have several [odds and ends](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/odds+and+ends) to tie up before I leave

Answer (score 1):

I think "must-see" would fit your context well.

> (*noun, Informal*) something, as a remarkable sight or entertainment, that should be seen or attended

[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary via [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/must-see)]

> a place or film considered to be essential to visit or see

[[Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/must-see)]

**Usage:**

> I have several ***must-sees*** to visit before I finish my vacation here.

Note that a ***must-see*** place is only highly recommended but not absolutely mandatory to visit.

#### Update:

The word "[***novelty attraction***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourist_attraction#Novelty_attraction)" can also be used in this context.

A novelty attraction is usually not a landmark but a place of interest due to its offbeat/intriguing/peculiar nature.

> I have several ***novelty attractions*** to visit before I finish my vacation here.

From Wikipedia,

> ***Novelty attractions*** are oddities such as the "biggest ball of twine" in Cawker City, Kansas, the Corn Palace in Mitchell, South Dakota, or Carhenge in Alliance, Nebraska, where old cars serve in the place of stones in a replica of Stonehenge. Novelty attractions are not limited to the American Midwest, but are part of Midwestern culture

Comment: Hi, BuscuitBoy, the OP is talking about places that aren't important (they certainly aren't landmarks),

Comment: I think of a _must-see_ as something on the beaten path, something that "everyone" goes to see. The O.P. seems to be talking about hidden gems, or a place to buy a bottle of water. That said, concerning the pier and the bookstore, we could say something like: _I have a few **personal must-sees** before I finish my vacation here_.

Comment: @Rathony - 
Yes. A must-see place need not necessarily be a landmark in my view. For example, if you are visiting the city of Agra in India, Taj Mahal is a landmark. Similarly, The palace of [Mariam-uz-Zamani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariam-uz-Zamani) is a recognized tourist attraction and a "must-see" but it is less popular than the Taj Mahal itself. So it is recommended for tourists but is not mandated.

Comment: I understand your point. But the OP is talking about grocery and book stores (using a word like an errand) which can't be a tourist attraction. It's up to you.

Comment: @Rathony It might be a *really, really good* bookstore.